# Difference between the windows installation of minGW64 and the MSYS2 shell installed version of minGW64

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw-w64, msys2

I have been using the minGW64 compiler with Visual studio code on windows for some time. However, there are certain limitations to it  when it comes to certain libraries. The absence of a make tool and the inability to execute a config script while compiling a c++ program being the main ones.  I came to know of MSYS, a tool provides a UNIX environment that allows us to do certain things that are forbidden by the windows terminal. I installed it but I saw that I need to install mingw64 again, from within the terminal to use it with MSYS2.

My question is, is there no way I can use my earlier mingw copy with this installation of MSYS2? Is there some difference between the mingw64 that comes with MSYS2 and the standard installation?

Comment: No, there's no particular difference, and you should be able to use your existing compiler if you add it to `PATH` (directly from the shell, since I think by default it doesn't respect PATH from Windows settings). But why would you? MSYS2 is one of the best MinGW distributions, consistently having an up-to-date GCC version and such.

Comment: My compiler is added directly to the path the MSYS didn't detect it. I had to reinstall mingw from within the MSYS shell in order to get it to work. I currently have 2 copies of mingw installed. One is standalone and other is installed in the MSYS2 directory.

I like the standalone mingw because it integrates nicely with VS code and its customizability settings, where I do all my work. MSYS forces you to use its shell for  all the important stuff.

Comment: Added to which PATH? As I said, MSYS2 doesn't respect system-wide PATH by default. Try running `echo $PATH` to see which PATH it uses.

Comment: *"because it integrates nicely with VS code"* MinGW from MSYS2 integrates with it exactly the same way. *"customizability settings"* What do you mean? Changes are, MSYS2 has similar settings.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I was thinking about the system-wide PATH. I added it to the MSYS specific path and it now works. Thanks a lot for your help.

When I was referring to "customizability" settings, I was talking about the task.json, launch.json and c_cpp_properties.json files that allow you to specify settings for your project. This can directly be used with Mingw inside the VS code terminal and it's quite convenient. I have yet to learn how to build makefiles so I rely on the VS code tools heavily.

Comment: The customization you're talking about show work exactly the same way with MSYS2 MinGW.